# Slim framework, cannot reach pdo sql server connection that is inside a container from a controller

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, slim

In my **app.php** I set up a container where I configure the database connection:

```
    $container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $db = $c['settings']['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $db['host'] . ";Database=" . $db['dbname'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));
    return $pdo;
};
```

and specify route and controller related information:

```
$container['CourseController'] = function($container)
{
    return new \App\Controllers\CourseController($container);
};

require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
```

In my **routes.php**, I have a single route:

```
<?php

$app->get('/courses', 'CourseController:getAll');
```

and below are my Controller.php and CourseController.php classes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Controller
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;        
    }

}

<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function getAll($request, $response)
    {
        try
        {
            $statement = $this->container->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Course");
            $statement->execute();

            $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($results));
            return $response;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting 500 error and unable to track down the problem. Here is what I know so far:

- I don't have any problems connecting to my database; if I put my
  routing code inside app.php i am able to retrieve the results of my
  query.
- I am passing the container to my controller. By using var_dump($this->container) on my controller I observe that container is fine.
- var_dump($this->container->db) is empty though. So, I am assuming that the pdo object wasn't passed or the connection was lost.
- I have tried this suggestion to no avail: "The sqlsrv extension will fail to connect when using error mode PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION (default). To connect, you will need to explicitly pass array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING) (or PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT) into the constructor, or override the getDefaultOptions() method when using sqlsrv." from https://github.com/FaaPz/Slim-PDO

Is there a way for me to pass my pdo connection properly to my controllers by using a container and not get a 500? I am open to other solutions as well if this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 500 because in your CourseController.php file, PHP tries to find PDO class under App\Controllers namespace.

You have to use a leading backslash to indicate that PDO is a global class:

```
$results = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means that a PHP error has occurred.

Firstly change your PDO instantiation to enable errors:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    "sqlsrv:Server=" . $db['host'] . ";Database=" . $db['dbname'],
    $db['user'],
    $db['pass'],
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
);
```

To view the errors directly, update your Slim settings to enable error display:

```
$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
    ],
];
$app = new Slim\App();
```

You should now see the error displayed. Alternatively look in the PHP error log and you should see it there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have the 2nd code and tried the  1st code you have shared. Problem is im running it on Azure and it wasn't giving me really detailed error logs (Or i couldn't find the necessary logs).